# phonegap, android, iOS Y navegadores web

Tags: android, ios, aplicación-web, phonegap

¿las aplicaciones desarrolladas en `Phonegap` sirven tanto para móviles (Android, iOS ) como para navegadores web (Firefox, Chrome, iExplore, etc)?.

para no tener código para móviles y para escritorio independientes.

Comment: recuerda que phonegap es el programa si quieres un framework puedes usar ionic

Answer (score 5):

La respuesta corta es **sí**

La respuesta larga es **depende** de como estructuras tu aplicación.

[Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) es una distribución de [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/). Esta soporta [Windows](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/index.html) 8, 8.1 y 10 además de [Ubuntu](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ubuntu/index.html). El inconveniente de esto es que tu aplicación no corre sobre el navegador sino como una aplicación independiente.

Este framework está diseñado para interactuar con el sistema operativo desde javascript y no impone ninguna regla en cuanto a que frameworks css o javascript debes utilizar. Básicamente lo que hace es crear una **aplicación** con un componente que es capaz de renderizar html, css y javascript (usualmente conocido como un webview). Este componente sirve html al igual que tu navegador por lo que las aplicaciones que funcionen en uno funcionarán también en el otro.

El problema reside en que tu navegador no permitirá que hagas llamadas al sistema operativo, si usas plugins esto puede ocurrir así que depende en su mayoría de que es lo que estas tratando de construir.

La regla de oro aquí es que puedes intentar reutilizar lo que hayas escrito que tenga que ver con lógica de presentación mientras que la lógica que tenga que ver con el sistema operativo es muy probable que no funcione a menos que distribuyas tu app como una aplicación independiente.

Ten en cuenta que este framework no fue diseñado para el navegador sino para el móvil y que **la mayoría** de los frameworks asociados a él intentarán hacer optimizaciones asumiendo que estás en un móvil.

La mejor forma de probar que tan compatible con el navegador puede ser tu aplicación es correrla con el [ripple-emulator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ripple-emulator) o abrirla en el mismo navegador. Usualmente verás muchos errores que te pueden dar indicios de que codigo puedes reutilizar y cual no.

Answer (score 1):

Si funcionan en android, IOS y desktop, pero añadiendo o quitando la carga de `phonegap.js` y dependiendo que si usas plugins que estén en Android y IOS o solo una de ellas.

Pongamos como ejemplo que quieres añadir soporte a `mensajes toast` en pantalla, hay un [Toast plugin para phonegap](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin) que funciona perfectamente en Android y IOS pero en Desktop cómo es normal no hay soporte para eso.
Deberás tener en cuenta estos pequeños aspectos.

Te recomiendo que te mires el [framework7](http://framework7.io/) está muy bien optimizado para IOS, Android con soporte de pieles simulando app nativas de cada plataforma, además que funciona muy bien en Chrome(desktop) y Firefox de escritorio.

El `framework7` es mucho más liviano comparado con el popular `Ionic+AngularJS`, además incluye un pequeño motor similar a la sintaxis de `JQuery`.
Lo he testeado con un ACER Liquid z200 - 512MB de Ram (Gama entrada) y va finas las apps no muy complejas.

Puedes aumentar el rendimiento en `Android` añadiendo `crosswalk` solución para las versiones inferiores a KITKAT

Answer (score 0):

Este Framework esta orientado principalmente para desarrollar aplicaciones móviles multiplataforma como son : iOS, Android, BlackBerry, Windows Mobile, etc.,  por medio del uso de tecnología web como Html, Javascript, css.

El framework phonegap se usa para portar tu aplicación web a un ambiente movil, lo que tendrías que hacer es realizar tu aplicación web que sea soportada en los navegadores que comentas firefox, chrome, iExplore, etc y posteriormente por medio de phonegap realizar adecuaciones para crear las versiones para móvil.

Answer (score 0):

Si desarrollas con cordova/phonegap tendrás problemas de seguridad y tanto apple como android te dirán que actualices tus aplicaciones, si tienes un par no pasa nada, pero si tienes muchas es un palo. Mi consejo sería este:
1.- Seguir este tutorial, que te muestra paso a paso como hacer aplicaciones que cargan urls externas: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzoqnd8UP-M

2.- Y aquí otro que usa un webview para cargar tu propio html. http://wobbabits.tumblr.com/post/107524782642/creating-a-hybrid-app-for-ios Un saludo!

Si tus aplicaciones son sencillas no es necesario usar cordova.

Espero te sea util la respuesta.
Un saludo,